# BGE Snake Game make objects follow the leader exactly?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have a basic BGE snake game, with the parts of the snake being spheres. It works, except I can't get the tail spheres follow the head... I have the original sphere moving and spawning spheres when it collects the red spheres, but I don't know how to make them follow in the exact path which the original sphere took...

Here's a link to the file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6_5f6jmSaHOWThxMHQ2MkJnWFk

Comment: As in your previous post I suggested using module mode if you are going to use global vars. `snekfollow(controller)` can be used as an entry point in Snake.py (ie could put all code in Snake.py). If you make a simple global list `snake = ["Sphere"]` (head only) and append the tail to the list every time you collect, eg after first `snake.append("Sphere.001")` in `Snake.snekfollow(cont)` then list is `["Sphere", "Sphere.001"]` Each tail in list can be given the location of the previous in `Snake.main()` before you set the new location of the head.

Comment: I'm really confused by your comment, but only because I'm a noobie. So what you're saying is that I can put all of the code in Snake.py and then I only need the python controller in the Sphere object's logic area? I'm also confused about the method of updating location... Would I have to abandon the `own.applyMovement()` function? Or am I missing something? Instead of the `own.applyMovement()` method, I'm thinging I could have two location variables and change the x/y by .2, then update the location. But then I don't think I can use this with the tail without having a bagillion variables...

Comment: No need for a  bagillion variables?..No need to abandon the `own.applyMovement()` method?  Instead of a separate script file for each of your game controllers you can use an entry point eg `Snake.add_tail(controller)` eg `def add_tail(controller):` function in the Snake.py module.  All your global vars would also be available to it.   Check out https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249757-Prof-Monster-s-BGE-Guide-to-Python-Coding